# SSL negotiation failed sending email using Indy with Office365

Tags: delphi, openssl, office365, indy

When using the Indy TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL class with Office365, we are receiving the message "SSL negotiation failed" sporadically. This is going on since two weeks ago.

It appears as if recently, Office365 has changed something in its service.

Has anybody experienced this behavior this days?

Thanks in advance,

A. Afonso

Comment: Is this related to [this discussion](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/5727-exception-message-error-connecting-with-ssl-eof-was-observed-that-violates-the-protocol/)?

Comment: @remy that fixed it for us. XE3 and latest OpenSSL dlls.